# Data between activity and adapter

Tags: android

I use BaseAdapter to show row of ListView.
The activity and adapter are writen in two different class.
In ListActivity, I use below code set data of row.

```
String[] FileName = {"a", "b", "c"};
MyAdapter a = new MyAdapter(this, FileName);
setListAdapter(a);
```

In adapter, it show FileName in each row.
But it may change the FileName.
So in activity, I want to get the array FileName which has been changed.
How can I do?

Adapter code:

```
private String[] name = null;
public BookmarkListAdapter(Context ctxt, String[] s) {
name = s;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewTag viewTag;
if(convertView == null) {
convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_bookmark_list, null);
viewTag = new ViewTag((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_bookmark_info));
convertView.setTag(viewTag);
}
else {
viewTag = (ViewTag) convertView.getTag();
}
viewTag.n.setText(name[position]);
name[position] = name[(position + 1) % 3];   //change
}
class ViewTag {
TextView n;
public ViewTag(TextView t) {
this.n = t;
}
}
```

In this example, the array change to {"b", "c", "a"}.
In activity, how to get the array which changed?

Comment: can you please modify the question to make it clear ?

Comment: Here you had hard coded the FileName.so it won't work for getting updated one.for that,you need to change the reference to FileName,that means,you should refer updated FileName instead of hard coding it just before using it in MyAdapter.

Comment: I already edit my code in problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
But it may change the FileName.
```

Do you mean to change in values of the `FileName` then you can call `youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and it will update your values.

Or if your mean to change the variable then you need to `reinstantiate` your adapter and pass the new variable name to it.

**Note:** If not necessary to change the varible name then don't do it and update the value every time you need.